# What conditions must an operator meet, to have only real eigenvalues?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

Given the problem $Lu = \lambda u$, what properties must $L$ have, for all its eigenvalues to be real? An answer in the context of (partial) differential equations would be appreciated.

Comment: I doubt they're the only ones, but I know Hermitian operators have all real eigenvalues.

Comment: There are examples of non-self-adjoint operators with strictly real spectra, so I suspect a comprehensive answer may not be easy.